# Questions in Topology/Real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $\mathcal U$ be an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb R^2$.So I have two questions:

Is there $r \gt 0$ such that $xy \le r^2\;\;\;\;\forall (x,y) \in \mathcal U$ ? (I mean there's for sure $r \gt 0$ such that $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_o)^2 \le r^2\;\;\;\forall (x,y),(x_0,y_0) \in \mathcal U\;\;$ since $\mathcal U$ is open but could somebody find $r \gt 0$ with this property?) If there isn't such $r$, what would be the upper bound then?

Could I choose $\varepsilon \gt 0$ as large as I want in order the product $\varepsilon xy$ would pe positive no matter what the sign of $xy\;is\;\;\;\forall (x,y) \in U$?

I'm new to topology/analysis so I would appreciate any help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first question is trivially yes. Just choose $R:=r+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$, then 
$\mathcal{U}\subset B_R(0)$, and for any $(x,y)\in B_{R}$ it holds $x,y\leq R$

To answer the second question: if $\epsilon>0$ then the sign of $xy\epsilon$ is nothing but the sign of $xy$.

Comment: @boon heT Oh Gosh, the second question I made was enough silly. Thank you for pointing it out! I 'm not pretty sure that I understood the answer to the first question though. If I choose $r+\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$ then how do I get $xy \le r^2$ ? thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: See my edit. It's just triangle inequality.

Comment: Yeah, I just did! Thank you a lot! you've been very helpful

Comment: @boon heT excuse me, Could I ask you something more? If we have $f \in\;\mathcal{C^3(U)\cup C(\bar U)}$ when $\mathcal U$ is the above one and we know that $f_{xy} \gt 0\;\;\forall (x,y) \in \mathcal U$ then, could we choose $\varepsilon \gt f_{xy}$? Is this mathematically correct?